# fetch query string parameters and display on pug generated page after form submission

Tags: express, pug, query-string

I'm working with express right now. I've built just a simple form that goes to a pug page generated via express after submitting:

```
 form.create-list(action='/test', method='get')
  fieldset
    legend Add your item
    label(for='item-name') Item: 
    input#name(type='text', name='name', required='')
    br
    label(for='item-name') Quantity: 
    input#quantity(type='text', name='quantity', required='')
    br
    br
    input(type='submit')
```

With the get method, I can see the name properties behind pulled into my URL: http://localhost:4000/test?name=hello&quantity=there

I would like to display specifically the name/quantity parameters on my pug page, but have been unsuccessful. In my routing file I used:

```
router.get('/test/:name', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('layout', {'title': req.param("name")});
});
```

And in my pug template just added the below line:
    p #{title}

Shouldn't that work? I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The value you should be looking for is `req.query.name` instead of `req.params.name`

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work

    router.get('/test/:name', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('layout', {'title':req.query.name});
    });

Im really not sure what im doing wrong lol..

Comment: Maybe loose the ‘’ only use `{ name : req.query.name }`